# If $\lim_{t \rightarrow 2} \frac{ \sqrt[3]{a+ \frac{b}{t^3}-2 } }{t-2}=A$, then what is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

If  $\lim_{t \rightarrow 2} \frac{ \sqrt[3]{a+ \frac{b}{t^3}-2} }{t-2}=A$, then what is

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 2}  \frac{ \sqrt[3]{ \frac{a}{8} + \frac{b}{8t^3}}-t+1 }{t^2+2t-8}$ in terms of A?

I factorized 1/2 out of the root, but i have no idea how to get rid of -t+1 and also (t+4)

Comment: Why is there a $-2$ in $\frac{ \sqrt[3]{a+ \frac{b}{t^3}-2} }{t-2}$ (the question) but not in the title?

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 2}  \frac{ \sqrt[3]{ \frac{a}{8} + \frac{b}{8t^3}}-t+1 }{t^2+2t-8}=$

$ \lim_{t \rightarrow 2}(\frac{1}{2} \frac{ \sqrt[3]{a+ \frac{b}{t^3}-2} }{t-2} )\frac{t-2}{t^2+2t-8}+\frac{1-t}{t^2+2t-8}$

that not exist because $\frac{1-t}{t^2+2t-8}$ it is not defined in $t=2$ and locally you have a form of type $\frac{1}{0}$